# When is JuggerNET bridge initialized?

Tags: content-delivery, java, iis-and-asp.net

I have a Tridion 2013SP1 Content Delivery .net web-application. In its `global.asax`, I am attempting to make a call that requires the JuggerNET bridge to be initialized (e.g. `new PageFactoryMeta()`).

I tried placing this code in `Application_Start`:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new PageMetaFactory(0);
}
```

But it doesn't behave consistently. Occasionally it works, but sometimes it throws the JuggerNET not initialized error:

```
[Exception: <JavaException>
  <Type>java/lang/ClassNotFoundException</Type>
  <Message><![CDATA[com.tridion.meta.PageMetaFactory]]></Message>
  <StackTrace><![CDATA[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tridion.meta.PageMetaFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.codemesh.bootstrap.JarInputStreamBootstrapper.forName(Unknown Source)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowException(Exception ex)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.init()
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.get_JObject()
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.init()
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.get_MethodPtr()
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.get_Handle()
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallObject(JavaProxy jpo, JavaMethodArguments args)
   at Com.Tridion.Meta.PageMetaFactory..ctor(Int32 publicationId)
   at Tridion.ContentDelivery.Meta.PageMetaFactory..ctor(Int32 publicationId)
   at ASP.global_asax.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\_GITHome\ExampleWebsite\Global.asax:line 10]]></StackTrace>
</JavaException>]
```

If I put the code in `Session_Start`, it works fine, but then it will be called every time a new session is created. I don't want that -- it should run only once.

Somewhere in between `Application_Start` and `Session_Start`, JuggerNET bridge is initialized. But where exactly?

Where would be the best place to put my code such that it is only executed once, and that is after JuggeNET has been initialized?

Comment: If you put in session start, can you use a singleton pattern to do it only once?

Comment: Indeed that would work as workaround. I'm trying to find the 'purest' solution :)

Comment: You say it throws a "not initialized" error, but the Exception you've pasted is Class not found.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of instantiating class object on session_start or application_start, I would recommend using dependency injection IOC container: [List of cotainers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx)

We have used **Autofac** in our implementation.

> While registering dependencies with Autofac, specify which class are
>   to be instatiated for each call vs which classes are to be
>   instantiated once per application.

[Reference for using autofac to achieve the same](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html)

Comment: I agree with what you are saying Hiren and that would solve the issue, but I still think it's a workaround :) At the moment I'm kinda of set to understand the lifecycle when JuggerNET bridge is created.

Comment: @MihaiCădariu If this is workaround then what kind of solution are you looking for? Web is stateless so instantiating something on per application, you will have to use: singleton implementation, application_start, IOC container. Since first option is reducing application scalability and second option application_start not working for you so only option left is IOC container suggested above.